# Java listFiles is not showing the current running file in its listing

Tags: java, arrays, file, io

so I have this program where I want to get the current list of files in the directory where the Java file is executing.

Here is the call:

```
File q1 = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File[] listOfFiles = sanitiseFileChecker(q1.listFiles());
```

And this is the `sanitiseFileChecker` method:

```
public void sanitiseFileChecker(File[] list){
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(list));
    for(int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(files.get(i).getName());
    }
}
```

This works perfectly except... my output is

```
Name.class
FOLDER
FILEA
FILEB
FILEC
```

But `Name.java` does not appear... I am confused why it is not being detected, can Java not detect a file listing when a java program is running?

Comment: I definitely am, I have another printout later confirming the location

Comment: How are you running this? And why do you expect to see the source file when you execute your program?

Answer (score -2):

This worked like expected to me:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ShowFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File userDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        File[] files = userDir.listFiles();

        System.out.println("Files in " + userDir.getAbsolutePath());

        for (File file : files) {
            System.out.println("\t" + file.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Sorry guys, my fault, I realised a mistake with concurrent removal from the list itself which caused the indexes to get mixed up.